# JQuery: Transfert content from local file to variable. (Same origin policy)

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, variables

I'm trying to create a local javascript application ( no server-side language )
The application have different text templates. I'd like 1 file per template.

But my problem is that I don't know how to transfert the content from the template to a variable. Same origin policy strike again !

**Attempt #1:**

I know the same origin policy, and I don't have any problem in doing a compromise on the dynamism by loading all template using a static list, such as:

```
<script src="tpl01.js"></script>
<script src="tpl02.js"></script>
...
```

Where I do have a problem, is when it come to put template content into a variable.
Template can have thousand of lines, and having to do that kind of things is extremly unpracticable ( and force me to escape everything ) :

```
templateSource = "line 1"
+ "line2"
+ "line3"
```

**Attempt #2:**

I also tried to load 1 template per iframe (that I then hide), but the main window can't talk to the iframe content, and the iframe content can't talk to the main window :

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   file:///home/dev/index.html from frame with URL
>   file:///home/dev/tpl.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

I try to be creative, but I'm running out of idea...

Do you know any **solution to put the content of a file into a variable** ?

Ps.: I don't mind adding a couple of line code per template, but I don't want to have to modify the whole content.

Note: The application will only be used on IE.